# Book series plot with a rough space marshal/soldier that drinks Wild Turkey from a hip flask

Tags: story-identification

When I was a teenager I read a couple of books from a series about a battle against some sort of aliens, possibly not on earth. The main character was a rough soldier/space marshal type character that drank Wild Turkey from a hip flask. Does this ring any bells for anyone?

Comment: Are there any more details you can think of, like was the main character part of a team or solo, what kind of weapons were used, anything about the aliens?  Also when we're you a teenager, was it 5 years ago or 25?

Comment: When were you a teenager? 1950? 2015? Were the books hardcover or paperback? American or British?

Comment: If you are going to bring whisky into space, why the heck would you bring Wild Turkey?

Comment: @Skooba: Drinking bad alcohol is a common trait in fiction to indicate that the person is so tough that they don't mind drinking the bad stuff with a minor suggestion that they're physically tough enough to resist the poisonous effects of the stuff that makes it less refined.

Comment: Is that Wild Turkey bourbon or rye whisky?

Comment: @user14111 good point, about 20+ years ago, so published before 1995.  I was in the UK, but given the bourbon it is likely an American series.

Comment: @Alith There weren't many - maybe 3 books in the series.  Don't remember any other significant events, main character had a lone wolf, and an intermittent side kick/love interest that was female.